# Quadrilateral $APBQ$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Quadrilateral $APBQ$ is incsribed in a circle $\omega$ with $\angle P = \angle Q = 90^{\circ}$ and $AP = AQ < BP$. Let $X$ be a variable point on segment $\overline{PQ}$. Line $AX$ meets $\omega$ again at $S$ (other than $A$). Point $T$ lies on arc $AQB$ of $\omega$ such that $\overline{XT}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{AX}$. Let $M$ denote the midpoint of chord $\overline{ST}$. As $X$ varies on segment $\overline{PQ}$, show that $M$ moves along a circle.

Comment: A picture would help to speed up parsing the text of the question.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question just to remove the complex-numbers tag as it doesn't seem to apply in this case.

Comment: what is $\omega$?

Comment: @robjohn ω is the circle circumscribing the quadrilateral. I'll edit the question on behalf of the original poster, to make it clear.

Comment: see discussion at: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5t175f5h1083097_quadrilateral_apbq

Comment: The easiest way to see this is to take $X$ to $P, Q,$ and the midpoint of $PQ.$ This immediately tells you that the center of the circle is the midpoint of $AO,$ where $O$ is the center of the circle. Then complex numbers gives a rather straightforward solution. Alternatively one can compute the lengths directly using Stewart's theorem, though this can get a bit messy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cleaner version of my attempt at an answer. It's still not complete but it's free of clutter and also identifies the circle $M$ is supposed to lie on. I also tried a solution based entirely on analytical geometry and I got very far but it's very messy. The picture below is a screen shot of an animation based on my analytical treatment. Too bad I can't upload the actual video since it's kinda cool to see $M$ moving in an arc of a circle as $X$ moves up and down.

[image]

Anyway, I am convinced that there is a relatively simple argument to prove that $\overline{CM}$ (see last picture below) is independent of $\mu$ but I haven't found it yet.

($|\mu| \le 1$ is a parameter that controls the movement of $X$ along the segment $\overline{PQ}$).

[image]
[image]
[image]